# Can't open and import files on Python

Tags: python-3.x

I just started learning Python this month with no prior coding knowledge. Before I could even get to practice coding, I was stuck with opening & importing files! To this end, I have no idea how to fix the problems as a newbie, so I will try to explain as best as I can.

*1. Opening files.*

Working directory is correct. The csv file was created with Geany on the Ubuntu operating system.

```
name=[]
age=[]
height=[]
with open(’/home/stephanie/chapter5exercise.csv’, encoding=’utf-8’,mode=’r’,newline=’’) as
csv file:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=’,’)
    for row in reader:
        name.append(row[0])
        age.append(row[1])
        height.append(row[2])
print("Done!")


**Error message:**

 File "<ipython-input-3-f801fef0d65e>", line 5
    with open(’/home/stephanie/chapter5exercise.csv’, encoding=’utf-8’,mode=’r’,newline=’’) as
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

*2. Importing files*

I downloaded a whatsapp chat text file for a coding exercise. It is stored in my Desktop environment. However, when I attempted to import it on Jupyter Notbook it didn't work.

I believe this is the problem, although I do not know how to work-around this:

the txt file's location as shown in my terminal:
**/Users/Mac/Desktop**

while the working directory as shown on Jupyter is:
**/home/stephanie/Desktop**

````
with open ("_chat.txt") as f:
    data = f.readlines()

**error message:** 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-07cb5c381c47> in <module>
----> 1 with open ("_chat.txt") as f:
      2     data = f.readlines()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '_chat.txt'```


Any input or advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks very much in advance!
````

Comment: The first it's because `’`is a weird quote that Python doesn't recognize. Use standard `"`s instead. For the second, double check your path, and/or use an absolute path to it if you want to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

For the first error, try changing the apostrophes in the open line. For example, change   `’/home/stephanie/chapter5exercise.csv’` to `'/home/stephanie/chapter5exercise.csv'`. 
Apparently, the apostrophe (’) that you are using is not the correct one.

For the second error, try giving the entire path of the txt file.

Comment: Thank you Bharat. I was able to easily fix the fist error with your help. For the second error, however, it did not work despite my attempt to use relative and absolute path.

Comment: Does the second error has to do with what I saw on the terminal "  /Users/Mac/Desktop " instead of " /home/stephanie/Desktop " ? I struggle to route the file through the right path because I couldn't simply do something like " Desktop/_chat.txt  ". Do you have any suggestions for this? Thank you.

Comment: Ok, one easiest way to do it is to upload it to your Jupiter Notebook, click on File >> Open, and upload _chat.txt there, so you can give the local path of the file directly in your code block (E.g. file = '/home/jovyan/FORMULA.rtf' ). You can use a tab if you are unsure about your path.